# "Local variable referenced before assignment" which was indeed not mentioned and the code has worked for several iterations

Tags: python, function, selenium

I'm working on Selenium on Python. I need to make the same procedure for more than 8000 URLs, so I defined the following function:

```
def obtenerFrecuencia(paradero):

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\chromedriver.exe')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
    driver.get(paradero)

    sleep(random.uniform(0, 0.3))

    id_base = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h3[@class="focus"]')

    for info in id_base:  # id
        variableunica = str(info.get_attribute("outerText")

    driver.quit()

    return variableunica
```

And I have the 8000 URLs saved on a list named links.

When I proceed to run the following code to store the findings of my code:

```
frecuencia = []

for link in links:
    temp = obtenerFrecuencia(link)
    frecuencia.append(temp)
```

I get the following error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'variableunica' referenced before assignment

However, I'm not referencing the local variable anywhere in the document so I don't really get why I have this problem. I have been reading other questions with the same problem but they are unrelated since no solutions mentioned have been worked so far or have even been related to my issue. So I thought it would be helpful to post the question here.

In addition, this error is shown at different iterations of the code, the highest was at 500 and the lowest at 21. So, the code is definitely working but I suppose It could be improved in order to get the information of the 8000 URLs in a row and avoid this error.

So the questions are the following:

- How can I avoid this error (how can I define the variable this way)?
- Why is it shown since I did not defined that local variable before?

Comment: This is most likely happening because `for info in id_base:` never enters the loop body, so when you `return variableunica` it won't be defined. It would **always be helpful to post the full error including the stack trace because that will point exactly at the line that is giving the error**

Comment: If in "obtenerFrecuencia" the "id_base" is empty, the variable is not set but returned which triggers the error.

Comment: Note, it is always a bit worrying to see a loop that simply assigns to a variable repeatedly. Is the assumption being made that there will always only be one item in the iterable? Or do you only care about the last one?

Comment: Thank you very much, I already defined the empty variableunica variable before the loop. I saw the answers before your comments @juanpa.arrivillaga so the code is now running and it takes a lot of time. However, as soon as it finishes I will rerun it with the error so other people with the same problem can find this question. I'll take that into account from now on.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't not really understood your last comment. For instance, I suppose you are referring to the loop I defined in the function, is that right? Since I don't really get it can you send me a question where this question is answered? I really hope to improve my coding skills and any resource received will be very helful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't declare the variableunica before use if your code does not go in info  loop then there is variable variableunica referenced before assignment

```
def obtenerFrecuencia(paradero):

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\chromedriver.exe')     # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
    driver.get(paradero)


    sleep(random.uniform(0, 0.3))

    id_base = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h3[@class="focus"]')
    variableunica=""
    for info in id_base:  # id
        variableunica = str(info.get_attribute("outerText")

    driver.quit()

    return variableunica
```

Comment: Thank you, now I can go to sleep. Tomorrow I will check how it turned out!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here.

```
id_base = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h3[@class="focus"]')
for info in id_base:  # id
    variableunica = str(info.get_attribute("outerText")
```

What if `id_base` is an empty list ?

Then it never loops through `id_base`  in the next line and `variableunica` is never assigned any value. And then you try to return it.

Solution:

Add

```
variableunica = ""
```

before entering the loop.